# I can't see changes in VS2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, git-for-windows

I'm new to use Git in Visual Studio 2015. If I work with a local project I can see the changes, but if I work with a project that located in a shared folder I can't see the changes and the authors. I'm using Easy Git extension, in it's history tab I can see all changes and in Git for Windows I can see all changes too. (Due to company regulations I'm not allowed to use Github or TFS.) If you need more information to help me out, please tell me.

[image]

Comment: Have you updated 2015 to latest version? And what do you mean by "in a shared folder"? If that "shared folder" means you have no remote it may not work, as evident from [this other question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34946042/267).

Comment: Yes, it's 14.0.25431.01 with update 3. I mean the shared folder, the project is on a virtual file server, not on a local machine.

Comment: And does that shared folder have a remote set up? Do you use push/pull?

Comment: I think not... I'm really new to use Git.

Comment: Well, if the answer I linked to above is correct, not having a remote means you won't get to see changes or authors in codelens.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! It helped me out!