# Visual Studio 2017/Team Foundation - Code with no author and no changes

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and I've downloaded some code from TFS. The issue is that all the code has "0 authors, 0 changes" (please see the screeshot below).
How is this possible? It shouldn't happen beacause everyone in the office is logged with his own account.

[image]

**Edit:**
 
Important infos:

- the solution has been created about one month ago by another user.
- CodeLens states "No changes in the last 12 months for this method"

Comment: Which specific version of VS 2017 do you use? What about other clients? Just try upgrading to the latest version, then try it again. Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814365/why-does-codelens-always-show-0-authors-0-changes

Comment: Is already up to date: Visual Studio Professional 2017 - Version 15.5.2. From another machine, identical client, identical result: 0 authors, 0 changes.

Comment: What's your TFS version? Can you see the information in TFS Web Portal/Code/File/Blame?

Answer (score 0):

Code Lens only looks at a certain amount of history (24 months).

If the last change is older than this then you'll see no changes.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it can't be the answer. The solution has been created one month ago.

Comment: @Flash that's significant information: please update the question (and also what does the message say when you hover over code lens?)