# Visual Studio 2019 Codelens always shows - 0 Authors 0 Changes when using git as Source Control

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, codelens

I am using Visual Studio 2019 specifically,

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Version 16.8.3
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.8.3+30804.86
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04084
Installed Version: Professional
```

I have my code being tracked my git.

However, Codelens with all options enabled still doesn't track any changes or authors, only references.

[image: codelens settings]

This is what happens in my code however,

[image: vs2019 codelens]

But the changes are tracked in git and are available when I click on `Show all file changes`

[image: show all file changes]

I tried every option I could imagine to get this working but I couldn't.

I tried the solutions  mentioned here [Why does CodeLens always show "0 authors, 0 changes"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814365/why-does-codelens-always-show-0-authors-0-changes) but those don't work either.

The code is not even 2 days old (I even set the option to 48 months as mentioned in the above SO post)

I don't want to completely reinstall Visual Studio right now because I can't (device policy).

I have the following Extensions installed.

- CodeMaid
- Viasfora
- Pinegap Dark Theme
- Github extension for Visual Studio

Comment: Question are the changes in the same branch you are working in?

Comment: @KenTucker Yes, There is only one branch `main` and no other branches, its even synced with a remote at github